# issue with Jquery Tables

Tags: php, jquery

I was given support on a previous question regarding selecting a TR directly after the previous - problem I'm facing now is when I added this SECOND TR to the table structure I'm loosing all the functions of the Jquery DataTables from https://datatables.net/ like the search and the page counter ext... if I remove that second TR it works fine - what am I missing? what's conflicting?

The HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--IMPORT GREYBOX -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var GB_ROOT_DIR = "/greybox/";
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
    <link href="greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table_idh').DataTable();});
    </script>
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand fa fa-car" href="#"><span style="color:orange;font-family: impact; margin-left: 5px;">MTC AUTO</span></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="addClient" href="addRecord.php" title="Add Client" rel="gb_page_center[500,500]">Add Client</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form action="inc/server.php?logout=true" method="POST">
        <input type="button" disabled class="btn btn-primary m15" value="Hello <? echo $username; ?>">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning m15" name="logout" value="Logout">
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 95px;">
    <table id="table_idh" class="display m95">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Date/Birth</th>
            <th>Income</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Get Records From Db-->
        <?php include 'inc/getRecords.php'; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
const $addClient = $('#addClient');

$addClient.hover(()=>{
    $addClient.css({"color":"red","text-decoration":"underline"});
},()=> {
    $addClient.css({"color":"black","text-decoration":"none"});
});

$('.trigger').on('click',(e) => {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

})

The Table Insert from database loop - that second TR is causing issue when I remove it I get all the functions back -

```
echo "
                <tr>
                    <td class='trigger'>".$firstName."</td>
                    <td>".$lastName."</td>
                    <td>".$phone."</td>
                    <td><a href='mailto:".$email."'>".$email."</a></td>
                    <td>".$dob."</td>
                    <td>".$emp_income."</td>
                    <td>".$dateIn."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='hide'>
                    <td colspan=7>Address: ".$address." <br> Province: ".$prov." <br> Postal Code: 

".$post." <br>RentOrOwn: ".$rent_or_own." <br>House Payment: ".$house_payment."<br>Shopping: ".$shopping."<br> Employer:".$emp_name."<br>Job Title: ".$emp_title."<br>Employment Time: ".$emp_time."<br>Downpayment: ".$downpayment." </td>
                    </tr>
                    ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use/load table activate code on the last.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table_idh').DataTable();
});
```

You can use it on the bottom of your page body.
And also load cdn.datatables.net files after load bootstrap files.
Footer/Bottom of the body will be best.

**#### Solution ####**

Solved the problem of colspan support by adding an "invisible" cell for every cell.

```
echo "
                <tr>
                    <td class='trigger'>".$firstName."</td>
                    <td>".$lastName."</td>
                    <td>".$phone."</td>
                    <td><a href='mailto:".$email."'>".$email."</a></td>
                    <td>".$dob."</td>
                    <td>".$emp_income."</td>
                    <td>".$dateIn."</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class='hide' >
                    <td width='100%'>
                        Address: ".$address." 
                        <br> Province: ".$prov." 
                        <br> Postal Code: ".$post." 
                        <br>RentOrOwn: ".$rent_or_own." 
                        <br>House Payment: ".$house_payment."
                        <br>Shopping: ".$shopping."
                        <br> Employer:".$emp_name."
                        <br>Job Title: ".$emp_title."
                        <br>Employment Time: ".$emp_time."
                        <br>Downpayment: xxx".$downpayment." 
                        </td>

                        <!-- hidden column 6 for proper DataTable applying -->
                         <td style='display: none'></td>
                         <td style='display: none'></td>
                         <td style='display: none'></td>
                         <td style='display: none'></td>
                         <td style='display: none'></td>
                         <td style='display: none'></td>
                         <td style='display: none'></td>
                    </tr>

                ";
```

Comment: Appreciate the input - but the placement of the these items isn't the issue, because again if I remove that second TR it works fine - I believe it's something IN the dataTables code that is searching to a certain amount of TR itself and by adding another it's messing up the logic???

Comment: Please check the solution again. I am edited the answer.

Comment: OMG thank you so much - can you please explain the solution to me as to what the issue was... please and thank you

Comment: oh wait, no - i mean worked to bring back the functions of the table itself but now the clicking of the name no longer brings up the hidden data instead it hides another record and seems at random..?

Comment: using still $('.trigger').on('click',(e) => {
  $(e.target).closest('tr').next('tr').toggleClass('hide');
 })

Comment: it's hidden the record directly under the one clicked instead of showing that hidden data?